# Controlling Version of Deployed Camunda BPM

Tags: camunda

Everytime I modify and deploy a process, the version number is increasing.I understand why it is increasing. But is there a to force to a predefined version and the deployments will override only that version. The reason is even for small bug fixes, I don't want the version to change.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about production or development?

In dev, you can configure the [processes.xml](http://docs.camunda.org/7.2/guides/user-guide/#process-applications-the-processesxml-deployment-descriptor) so all instances and old version of the process are removed:

```
<process-archive>
    <properties>
      <property name="isDeleteUponUndeploy">true</property>
    </properties>
</process-archive>
```

On production, you would not want to delete running or completed instances. You might want to migrate running instances to the next version, but that is not generic, it depends on the process and the changes made. Make sure to read [process-versioning-version-migration](http://docs.camunda.org/latest/guides/user-guide/#process-engine-process-versioning-version-migration) from the user guide.

A third approach would be to work with calls to services (expressions/delegates/listeners) instead of hard modelling inside the bpmn. If for example you write "${price > 500}" at an exclusice gateway flow, you will have a new process version when you deploy a "fix" with the value "1000". If you design your process application that it calls "${myPriceCalculator.limitExceeded(price)}", you can deploy a new war, but the process remains untouched.

Answer (score 1):

no this does not work. You can deploy a new version and delete the old one.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find any UI to delete old versions. Is there a way to automate this or any examples?

Comment: You can use the REST api in order to [delete a deployment](http://docs.camunda.org/latest/api-references/rest/#deployment-delete-single-deployment).

Answer (score 0):

Camunda REST will help you to deploy and delete the version of deployment. You just have to pass deployment `id`:

If you are using separated Camunda process engine(server) then your REST API to delete deployment will be:

```
http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/deployment/fa9af59a-382b-11ea-96d8-5edcd02b4f71
```

or if your Camunda process engine integrated with spring boot application then your URL will be:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/deployment/fa9af59a-382b-11ea-96d8-5edcd02b4f71
```

**Or**

You would have a process.xml file in resource folder of your application. You can set isDeleteUponUndeploy to true. So on every Undeployment of workflow, your workflow file will get deleted.

```
<process-archive>
    <properties>
      <property name="isDeleteUponUndeploy">true</property>
    </properties>
</process-archive>
```

**Or**

You and delete from Camunda UI as well the link is: http://localhost:8080/app/cockpit/default/#/dashboard

Now goto deployment and select your deployed version and click on delete version.